# Change WAMP server url on LAN

Tags: url, networking, wampserver, lan

I'm creating a web system for our network. I can successfully access the server using the computer name plus the port number. Is it possible of I mask the url and change it to something easier to type?

Comment: Do you have an in-house DNS Server?

Comment: Yes we do have an in-house DNS Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are simply accessing it from one computer, you can always modify the local [host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file and put in a URL that you want to access the server with.
If many computer need to access it, you may need a dns server in your network to manage that.  There are also freedns solutions for you: http://freedns.afraid.org/  and this would work fine if your server has a static IP or you can use NAT in your router.